# Клиентский сертификат nginx

Tags: nginx, https, ssl

Хочу настроить клиентский сертификат только для определенного location. Грубого говоря все url открыты для всех, а 1 закрыт. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://fardog.io/blog/2017/12/30/client-side-certificate-authentication-with-nginx/ https://habr.com/post/213741/

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: было бы правильно если бы ты написал тут в виде ответа краткий гайд по этой задаче

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы защитить клиентским сертификатом только определенного location нужно проверить значение $ssl_client_verify:

```
server {
        ...
        ssl_client_certificate vkapi.crt; #клиентский сертификат 
        ssl_verify_client optional; #проверять клиентский сертификат опционально, результат в $ssl_client_verify
        ...
        location /private {
            #защищенный location
            if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
                return 403;
            }
            ...
        }
        location / {
            #общедоступный location
            ...
        }
        ...
}
```